# Get TLS certificate chain after failed connection

Tags: ssl, go, certificate

I have a Go program that uses `tls.Server` to accept TLS connections from clients. When a particular client connects, I'm getting the error "tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

I'd like to see the certificate chain that was presented (and failed to verify) so that I can figure out what the client is doing wrong. Is there a way to do that using Go's `tls` package? The obvious answer - to use the `ConnectionState` method - doesn't work because the `ConnectionState`'s `PeerCertificates` field is only populated after the handshake has completed successfully.

Comment: It seems it would be easier to simply ask the client for the certificate it's presenting directly? The error is pretty specific, so I assume you just intend to diagnose the issue offline anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately it's rather difficult to figure out what certificate the client is presenting without just accepting a connection from them - it's one part of a large, complex system, and these client connections are automated.

Comment: But you should be able to determine what client it was, right? At least its IP address?

Comment: If you can't get it directly, and this is for a one-off debugging issue, I would probably just directly patch the x509 Verify method to log what you're looking for. There's no way to get the cert out of the handshake otherwise.

Comment: Ah, oh well. If that's what I have to do, I'll do it. Thanks!